# AIX спам в файле /etc/security/failedlogin

Tags: ssh, sftp, failedlogin

В AIX недавно стало пропадать место в каталоге `/etc`, виновником оказался файл `/etc/security/failedlogin`.

Выгрузил все в файл для анализа:

```
who -a /etc/security/failedlogin >/tmp/failedlogin

superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:30      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
superadmin       — ssh         Sep 22 16:31      ?
```

Оказалось, что один пользователь забил весь журнал. Это некий сервис на другом хосте который постоянно мониторит, есть ли файлы для него по протоколу SFTP.
Данный сервис работает без сбоев. В ручном режиме тоже спокойно можно зайти по SFTP под пользователем `superuser`.

Для дальнейшего анализа включил дебаг, чтоб увидеть подробности в файле `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Sep  4 17:10:41 db-bo-test auth|security:info syslog: ssh: failed login     attempt for superadmin from 192.168.33.175
Sep  4 17:10:41 db-bo-test auth|security:info sshd[37945458]: Accepted     password for superadmin from 192.168.33.175 port 52260 ssh2
Sep  4 17:10:44 db-bo-test auth|security:info syslog: ssh: failed login     attempt for superadmin from 192.168.33.175
Sep  4 17:10:44 db-bo-test auth|security:info sshd[34144358]: Accepted password for superadmin from 192.168.33.175 port 52261 ssh2
Sep  4 17:10:56 db-bo-test auth|security:info syslog: ssh: failed login attempt for superadmin from 192.168.33.175
Sep  4 17:10:56 db-bo-test auth|security:info sshd[34013270]: Accepted password for superadmin from 192.168.33.175 port 52266 ssh2
```

Как видно пароль проходит, но записи с *failed login* тоже есть.

Вот тут я дальше не знаю куда смотреть, необходимо понять почему вообще появляются данные записи. Прошу помочь знающих людей.

cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Group staff
ForceCommand  internal-sftp -u 73
Match User superuser
ForceCommand  internal-sftp -u 73
```

crontab -l

```
#0 3 * * * /usr/sbin/skulker
#45 2 * * 0 /usr/lib/spell/compress
#45 23 * * * ulimit 5000; /usr/lib/smdemon.cleanu > /dev/null
0 11 * * * /usr/bin/errclear -d S,O 30
0 12 * * * /usr/bin/errclear -d H 90
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /usr/sbin/dumpctrl -k >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
0 15 * * *  /usr/lib/ras/dumpcheck >/dev/null 2>&1
55 23 * * * /var/perf/pm/bin/pmcfg  >/dev/null 2>&1     #Enable PM Data Collection
```

Comment: Честно говоря не уверен, что принесёт результат, но попробуйте tcpdump'ом глянуть что идёт с 192.168.33.175. Вдруг что интересное увидите.

Comment: у вас новый дочерный процесс не запускается? 
не могли бы вывести `crontab -l` ?
что в `sshd_config` `PermitRootLogin ` ?

Comment: Добавил в тело вопроса crontab -l и ssd_config

Comment: Процессы запускаются, не понятно почему пишет в журнал, что failed login.

Comment: что ты получаешь при выполнении `ssh -v -l superadmin  etr6506l3-aix93.ca.com`?

Comment: @igaraev такая ошибка возникает, когда сервер не может связаться с сервером аутентификации.
Если логиниться (независимо от того правильный или неправильный пароль) производится в то время, когда учетная запись заблокирована - это дает сообщение `Failed password for invalid user ..`

попытка залогиниться с неверным паролем, когда учетная запись не заблокирована - это дает сообщение  `Failed password for`

вот тут возможно ответ на твой вопрос имеется http://systemcentercore.com/?GetElement=Microsoft.ACS.AIX.5.3.Ssh.Failed&Type=Rule&ManagementPack=Microsoft.ACS.AIX.5.3&Version=6.1.7000.269

Comment: Доступ к внешней сети закрыт. Так что проверить ssh -v -l superadmin etr6506l3-aix93.ca.com не получится. И журнал failedlogin заполняется на стороне сервера.

Comment: У нас не используется сервер аутентификации. И в ссылке что вы дали, failed password - это другая ошибка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46289/discussion-between-senior-automator-and-igaraev).